# Is it possible to execute a binary located inside a macOS app's sandbox container?

Tags: swift, macos, process, appstore-sandbox

Is it possible to execute a binary located inside a macOS app's sandbox container?

As a test, I tried using `Process()` to run the PHP binary. This works fine when running the PHP found at `usr/bin/php` but if I copy that into the app's sandbox container, it won't run. The error is `launch path not accessible`.

Steps to demonstrate the issue:

1. Put this in a bare sandboxed app's `ViewController`:

   ```
   let path = "/usr/bin/php"

   let process = Process()
   process.launchPath = path
   process.arguments = ["-v"]
   process.launch()
   ```
2. Result in the console:

   ```
   PHP 7.1.16 (cli) (built: Apr  1 2018 13:14:42) ( NTS )
   ```
3. Change the path in the code above, to:

   ```
   let documentsURL = FileManager.default.urls(for: .documentDirectory, in: .userDomainMask)[0]
   let path = documentsURL.absoluteString + "php"
   print(path)
   ```
4. The correct path is printed to the console:

`file:///Users/myuser/Library/Containers/com.domain.SandboxedApp/Data/Documents/php`

5. Copy the PHP binary to the container:

   ```
   $ cp /usr/bin/php /Users/myuser/Library/Containers/com.domain.SandboxedApp/Data/Documents
   ```
6. The resulting error in the console:

`2018-07-01 20:08:30.630442+1200 SandboxedApp[43579:20898286] Failed to set (contentViewController) user defined inspected property on (NSWindow): launch path not accessible`

Why won't `Process()` run PHP from the container? And why such a weird error message?

*(nb you could ask why I would want to do this. There are several reasons eg I would like to understand more deeply how the sandbox permissions work; I would like to sandbox an app which is able to run user-supplied binaries not provided by macOS nor distributed in the app's bundle — yes, not intended for distribution on the MAS, I know this breaks their terms).*